# WPF Command not bound randomly

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I see some buggy code from WPF project. ViewModelBase and RelayCommand classes are from MVVM Light. This is viewmodel class of a child window

```
class TOSelectionWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    ObservableCollection<ToElement> MyTo;

    public RelayCommand<ToAll> ToAddCmd { private set; get; }

    private Element selectedelement;
    public Element SelectedElement
    {
        get { return selectedelement; }
        set
        {
            if (value != selectedelement)
            {
                selectedelement = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedElement");
            }
        }
    }

    public TOSelectionWindowViewModel(Element e)
    {
        SelectedElement = e;

        System.Console.WriteLine( object.ReferenceEquals(e, SelectedElement) ); // True
        System.Console.WriteLine(object.Equals(e, SelectedElement)); // True

        ToAddCmd = new RelayCommand<ToAll>((Added) =>
        {
        if (Added == null )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("COMMAND EXECUTED", "Message",
                         MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
               return;
            }
            using (ToElementEntities my = new ToElementEntities(@"Data Source = " + Globals.Directory + @"\DB\" + Globals.SelectedVessel.ID + @"\El_TO.db"))
            {
                my.ToElements.Add(new ToElement { ElementID = e.ID });
                my.SaveChanges();
                MyTo = new ObservableCollection<ToElement>(my.ToElements.Where(i => i.ElementID == SelectedElement.ID));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This window is shown like this:

```
TOSelectionWindow toselectionWindow = new TOSelectionWindow(SelectedElement);
//SelectedElement is a property of this VM
if (toselectionWindow.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    ...
}
```

Problem is that ToAddCmd is executed or not executed randomly after I'm opening and closing this child window.
When I'd changed

```
my.ToElements.Add(new ToElement { ElementID = e.ID });
```

to

```
my.ToElements.Add(new ToElement { ElementID = SelectedElement.ID });
```

it started to work just fine even corrected line of code isn't called due to return statement. Can you explain me why?

Comment: What actually triggers the command? Is it bound to something in XAML?

Comment: What about putting a breakpoint in the command's execute method and looking at the call stack for hints?

Comment: @BradleyUffner Yes, it's bound to a button in a View: <telerik:RadButton x:Name="ToAddButton"                         Command="{Binding ToAddCmd}"
                     CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=PossibleTO}">
            </telerik:RadButton>

Comment: @EdPlunkett Had same idea, in both cases call stacks are same and in case of not executing command breakpoint doesn't work

Comment: I just want to understand why 1) I should use additional property in this VM to hold Element object in it and can't use contructor's parameter and 2) all-time normal executing of this command depends on the code which this command execute() method contains

Comment: @L.Volkov From the links grek40 just posted, it sounds like this is due to `RelayCommand` allowing the `Action` of your command to get garbage collected, due to it holding the only reference to it with a `WeakReference`.  The solution seems to be not using an anonymous function as the action.  I've never run in to this myself, so I can't say with cirtainty, but it sounds very plausable.

Comment: ...or use one of the tricks in his 2nd link to keep it from getting collected.

Comment: @grek40 it seems that so, thanks!

Comment: Well then feel free to upvote my answer over there ;), but this one should be closed as a duplicate. Don't delete it though, it's actually good to have a few duplicates with different titles around, as long as a problem is not part of the *common knowledge*